# Xbox 360 slim freezing after five mins of playing

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

Xbox freezing after five mins of play.

Things that I've tried so far:

1. Cleaned heatsink and cpu and replaced thermal paste.
2. Replaced cpu fan.
3. Replaced cables.

Has plenty of ventilation and even with no internet or hard drive, still freezes. When optical drive is out and playing via wifi it still freezes.

Power supply is good, green light all the time and not over heating.

Cache has been cleared and RT+Y on startup done as well.

Is there anything else that could cause it to freeze after five mins or so of playing?

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What is the date on the xbox?

Comment: The date on the optical drive is April 2011

Comment: No, I mean the date that is set in the system. A date e.g. before 1990 or after 3000 could cause problems.

Comment: Cool, I'm going to clean it again and then will power it up and get the details

Comment: System is set to current date and time. Have cleaned all the parts but it's still freezing after about five mins of gameplay.

Comment: Just to confirm I had a reflow done on it and it was screwed. The CPU itself must be done so having to sell the parts and get a used one instead. If you've done the above and the Xbox is freezing after five mins play without a red dot error, you're unfortunately screwed.

Comment: Ive heard of Xboxes being bricked for less then what you reported trying. Next time, if your xbox starts freezing up, the first thing I would try is a new harddrive. Fixed a very similar issue for me. I would speculate that this may have been your initial issue, and that more damage was done by opening it up.

Answer (score -3):

the problem with xbox 360 is indeed overhead the only solution that works for me is strip the plastic casing the console needs way more air than its desinged do suck in as soon as you remove the plastic casing and the console has room to breath you should not have a freeze anymore a fair WARNING never touch the consoles metal when you stripped it 9 out of 10 you get a shock hope this helps

Comment: copy-pasting answers on different questions is not helpful, also this does not seem like a good idea at all

Comment: im only saying what helped for me and the question was basicly the same as the other one so im not going to type a new reply when its the same solution and hey i didnt desing a console that overheats i cant help it that companys desing their products to break down after waranty u have to think like this if they made a console that dousnt brake they dont earn much proffit sadly we are not in the 80's anymore where a company would rather have a happy costummer base instead of thinking about their proffits